# ChartJS Recreate Chart

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to figure out how to recreate this Chart as close as possible using ChartJS.

https://www.chartjs.org/

The biggest issue I'm having is surrounding is how to plot the data X axis. Each point on the graph represents a second.

[image]

Sample Json:

```
{"type":"line","data":{"datasets":[{"type":"line","fill":false,"data":[59.0,57.0,57.0,58.0,57.0,56.0,57.0,55.0,62.0,63.0,62.0,62.0,69.0,63.0,62.0,61.0,62.0,62.0,66.0,69.0,72.0,72.0,75.0,82.0,84.0,85.0,84.0,81.0,91.0,90.0,87.0,87.0,89.0,90.0,90.0,86.0,86.0,86.0,86.0,83.0,83.0,82.0,81.0,85.0,89.0,85.0,83.0,87.0,81.0,81.0,81.0,91.0,90.0,81.0,87.0,83.0,98.0,90.0,81.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,90.0,90.0,90.0,92.0,90.0,91.0,90.0,88.0,81.0,83.0,91.0,88.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,90.0,87.0,88.0,91.0,88.0,86.0,86.0,87.0,86.0,91.0,90.0,91.0,92.0,91.0,91.0,88.0,87.0,88.0,95.0,94.0,92.0,92.0,91.0,88.0,88.0,90.0,88.0,90.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,88.0,91.0,88.0,91.0,94.0,90.0,90.0,88.0,88.0,87.0,88.0,87.0,88.0,86.0,86.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,90.0,88.0,79.0,74.0,83.0,85.0,83.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,83.0,90.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,85.0,86.0,87.0,87.0,91.0,90.0,90.0,90.0,90.0,90.0,86.0,85.0,85.0,86.0,86.0,86.0,86.0,85.0,85.0,86.0,86.0,85.0,85.0,83.0,85.0,87.0,85.0,86.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,86.0,91.0,92.0,88.0,85.0,87.0,86.0,86.0,85.0,86.0,86.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,87.0,92.0,88.0,83.0,85.0,87.0,87.0,90.0,85.0,87.0,87.0,86.0,85.0,85.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,90.0,91.0,86.0,87.0,87.0,86.0,90.0,87.0,90.0,90.0,94.0,92.0,91.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,90.0,91.0,92.0,90.0,86.0,88.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,87.0,88.0,88.0,87.0,88.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,88.0,88.0,91.0,90.0,90.0,91.0,91.0,87.0,90.0,92.0,87.0,86.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,88.0,92.0,92.0,81.0,78.0,79.0,83.0,86.0,87.0,88.0,87.0,87.0,85.0,85.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,87.0,86.0,86.0,85.0,86.0,86.0,85.0,85.0,87.0,86.0,88.0,90.0,91.0,90.0,95.0,97.0,98.0,95.0,97.0,97.0,97.0,97.0,98.0,95.0,95.0,108.0,95.0,95.0,95.0,91.0,78.0,83.0,82.0,92.0,89.0,88.0,85.0,86.0,94.0,94.0,97.0,99.0,99.0,97.0,95.0,91.0,92.0,94.0,95.0,92.0,94.0,94.0,95.0,92.0,94.0,94.0,95.0,95.0,92.0,94.0,97.0,95.0,95.0,94.0,102.0,104.0,99.0,98.0,95.0,94.0,91.0,94.0,94.0,91.0,92.0,91.0,92.0,97.0,94.0,92.0,91.0,97.0,95.0,109.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,110.0,112.0,112.0,109.0,110.0,112.0,109.0,105.0,104.0,102.0,100.0,105.0,102.0,102.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,104.0,104.0,105.0,107.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,105.0,105.0,104.0,104.0,107.0,104.0,102.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,105.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,110.0,112.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,105.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,112.0,117.0,110.0,109.0,116.0,114.0,112.0,112.0,110.0,110.0,109.0,104.0,112.0,116.0,114.0,116.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,110.0,109.0,105.0,112.0,114.0,110.0,110.0,114.0,116.0,112.0,107.0,112.0,107.0,110.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,109.0,110.0,114.0,110.0,110.0,114.0,112.0,112.0,116.0,117.0,117.0,117.0,114.0,114.0,109.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,114.0,110.0,107.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,110.0,114.0,112.0,109.0,114.0,110.0,112.0,114.0,116.0,110.0,112.0,112.0,119.0,121.0,119.0,117.0,114.0,110.0,114.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,105.0,104.0,105.0,105.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,105.0,102.0,105.0,102.0,107.0,104.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,112.0,110.0,110.0,110.0,112.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,107.0,112.0,110.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,114.0,112.0,109.0,107.0,112.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,110.0,112.0,112.0,109.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,109.0,107.0,110.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,112.0,114.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,104.0,107.0,116.0,114.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,110.0,110.0,107.0,95.0,94.0,80.0,83.0,85.0,92.0,98.0,100.0,98.0,98.0,97.0,100.0,104.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,102.0,102.0,100.0,104.0,107.0,105.0,107.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,117.0,98.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,100.0,100.0,104.0,107.0,107.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,107.0,110.0,112.0,112.0,109.0,105.0,119.0,104.0,91.0,88.0,95.0,105.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,109.0,105.0,100.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,105.0,104.0,105.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,100.0,104.0,104.0,109.0,105.0,104.0,114.0,116.0,112.0,110.0,110.0,112.0,107.0,112.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,102.0,105.0,107.0,109.0,112.0,109.0,107.0,104.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,110.0,110.0,109.0,105.0,105.0,104.0,107.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,105.0,102.0,107.0,105.0,107.0,104.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,104.0,102.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,110.0,107.0,109.0,105.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,104.0,104.0,110.0,112.0,112.0,114.0,117.0,112.0,114.0,112.0,112.0,110.0,121.0,117.0,117.0,112.0,114.0,116.0,110.0,109.0,112.0,110.0,110.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,100.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,109.0,105.0,107.0,102.0,102.0,107.0,104.0,105.0,104.0,100.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,98.0,102.0,105.0,105.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,100.0,100.0,98.0,100.0,100.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,107.0,104.0,107.0,105.0,102.0,105.0,107.0,112.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,105.0,105.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,110.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,102.0,102.0,107.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,112.0,109.0,105.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,116.0,110.0,107.0,107.0,116.0,110.0,104.0,107.0,107.0,110.0,116.0,116.0,119.0,112.0,112.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,110.0,114.0,112.0,110.0,116.0,109.0,110.0,110.0,116.0,110.0,109.0,110.0,107.0,107.0,105.0,107.0,114.0,109.0,109.0,105.0,105.0,102.0,109.0,109.0,105.0,107.0,105.0,104.0,105.0,109.0,107.0,105.0,112.0,114.0,112.0,114.0,116.0,118.0,115.0,115.0,115.0,116.0,122.0,118.0,116.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,116.0,118.0,118.0,120.0,118.0,115.0,109.0,111.0,116.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,120.0,118.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,111.0,116.0,115.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,109.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,104.0,111.0,107.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,106.0,106.0,104.0,107.0,107.0,104.0,109.0,124.0,120.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,113.0,118.0,115.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,115.0,113.0,99.0,96.0,104.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,113.0,118.0,116.0,115.0,111.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,115.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,111.0,115.0,115.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,120.0,116.0,120.0,115.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,111.0,106.0,107.0,113.0,111.0,115.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,106.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,109.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,111.0,113.0,107.0,109.0,115.0,109.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,116.0,111.0,106.0,111.0,107.0,109.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,104.0,104.0,109.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,111.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,109.0,111.0,115.0,113.0,111.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,111.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,115.0,116.0,116.0,116.0,113.0,113.0,109.0,109.0,115.0,109.0,100.0,96.0,89.0,107.0,104.0,104.0,109.0,106.0,111.0,109.0,104.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,104.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,115.0,113.0,109.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,106.0,109.0,106.0,104.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,107.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,102.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,109.0,109.0,106.0,107.0,109.0,113.0,115.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,102.0,104.0,106.0,106.0,107.0,106.0,111.0,111.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,107.0,104.0,106.0,107.0,109.0,113.0,109.0,111.0,116.0,116.0,115.0,107.0,107.0,113.0,109.0,106.0,102.0,104.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,111.0,113.0,113.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,104.0,106.0,106.0,109.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,106.0,109.0,106.0,106.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,100.0,102.0,100.0,100.0,99.0,97.0,99.0,100.0,100.0,99.0,100.0,99.0,102.0,104.0,102.0,99.0,99.0,102.0,102.0,100.0,97.0,97.0,97.0,97.0,100.0,99.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,104.0,115.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,115.0,113.0,115.0,109.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,104.0,106.0,116.0,115.0,111.0,111.0,106.0,106.0,111.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,106.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,100.0,104.0,102.0,100.0,99.0,99.0,100.0,99.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,99.0,100.0,97.0,99.0,97.0,102.0,100.0,100.0,100.0,99.0,99.0,97.0,99.0,97.0,99.0,96.0,97.0,96.0,97.0,96.0,100.0,104.0,100.0,104.0,102.0,106.0,106.0,104.0,104.0,102.0,99.0,113.0,115.0,109.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,115.0,124.0,124.0,115.0,118.0,116.0,115.0,113.0,122.0,120.0,116.0,122.0,118.0,118.0,120.0,109.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,113.0,113.0,115.0,116.0,113.0,115.0,118.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,106.0,107.0,113.0,118.0,122.0,122.0,118.0,118.0,122.0,120.0,118.0,113.0,115.0,115.0,111.0,120.0,60.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,113.0,111.0,109.0,99.0,100.0,96.0,99.0,102.0,109.0,102.0,104.0,111.0,107.0,107.0,104.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,102.0,104.0,107.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,111.0,106.0,104.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,107.0,113.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,104.0,106.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,106.0,113.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,109.0,111.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,115.0,115.0,109.0,116.0,113.0,109.0,111.0,116.0,120.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,115.0,115.0,111.0,113.0,107.0,107.0,109.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,115.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,109.0,106.0,109.0,106.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,111.0,113.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,109.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,115.0,111.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,116.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,113.0,109.0,106.0,107.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,104.0,107.0,107.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,102.0,102.0,106.0,106.0,104.0,102.0,100.0,111.0,109.0,115.0,128.0,128.0,120.0,120.0,120.0,115.0,116.0,115.0,115.0,118.0,120.0,120.0,124.0,115.0,118.0,113.0,111.0,115.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,109.0,107.0,113.0,111.0,113.0,109.0,111.0,107.0,106.0,107.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,106.0,104.0,104.0,106.0,107.0,111.0,109.0,106.0,106.0,109.0,107.0,106.0,111.0,115.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,115.0,115.0,109.0,109.0,111.0,111.0,109.0,120.0,115.0,113.0,115.0,116.0,111.0,109.0,113.0,116.0,118.0,106.0,99.0,89.0,97.0,99.0,100.0,107.0,104.0],"label":"Output"}]},"options":{}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Closes I can come for you is this:

```js
let data = [59.0, 57.0, 57.0, 58.0, 57.0, 56.0, 57.0, 55.0, 62.0, 63.0, 62.0, 62.0, 69.0, 63.0, 62.0, 61.0, 62.0, 62.0, 66.0, 69.0, 72.0, 72.0, 75.0, 82.0, 84.0, 85.0, 84.0, 81.0, 91.0, 90.0, 87.0, 87.0, 89.0, 90.0, 90.0, 86.0, 86.0, 86.0, 86.0, 83.0, 83.0, 82.0, 81.0, 85.0, 89.0, 85.0, 83.0, 87.0, 81.0, 81.0, 81.0, 91.0, 90.0, 81.0, 87.0, 83.0, 98.0, 90.0, 81.0, 88.0, 88.0, 88.0, 88.0, 90.0, 90.0, 90.0, 92.0, 90.0, 91.0, 90.0, 88.0, 81.0, 83.0, 91.0, 88.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 88.0, 90.0, 87.0, 88.0, 91.0, 88.0, 86.0, 86.0, 87.0, 86.0, 91.0, 90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 91.0, 91.0, 88.0, 87.0, 88.0, 95.0, 94.0, 92.0, 92.0, 91.0, 88.0, 88.0, 90.0, 88.0, 90.0, 87.0, 87.0, 88.0, 88.0, 91.0, 88.0, 91.0, 94.0, 90.0, 90.0, 88.0, 88.0, 87.0, 88.0, 87.0, 88.0, 86.0, 86.0, 87.0, 87.0, 88.0, 90.0, 88.0, 79.0, 74.0, 83.0, 85.0, 83.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 90.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 87.0, 91.0, 90.0, 90.0, 90.0, 90.0, 90.0, 86.0, 85.0, 85.0, 86.0, 86.0, 86.0, 86.0, 85.0, 85.0, 86.0, 86.0, 85.0, 85.0, 83.0, 85.0, 87.0, 85.0, 86.0, 88.0, 88.0, 88.0, 86.0, 91.0, 92.0, 88.0, 85.0, 87.0, 86.0, 86.0, 85.0, 86.0, 86.0, 87.0, 87.0, 88.0, 87.0, 92.0, 88.0, 83.0, 85.0, 87.0, 87.0, 90.0, 85.0, 87.0, 87.0, 86.0, 85.0, 85.0, 87.0, 87.0, 88.0, 90.0, 91.0, 86.0, 87.0, 87.0, 86.0, 90.0, 87.0, 90.0, 90.0, 94.0, 92.0, 91.0, 87.0, 87.0, 88.0, 90.0, 91.0, 92.0, 90.0, 86.0, 88.0, 87.0, 87.0, 88.0, 87.0, 88.0, 88.0, 87.0, 88.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 88.0, 88.0, 91.0, 90.0, 90.0, 91.0, 91.0, 87.0, 90.0, 92.0, 87.0, 86.0, 88.0, 88.0, 88.0, 88.0, 92.0, 92.0, 81.0, 78.0, 79.0, 83.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0, 87.0, 87.0, 85.0, 85.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 87.0, 86.0, 86.0, 85.0, 86.0, 86.0, 85.0, 85.0, 87.0, 86.0, 88.0, 90.0, 91.0, 90.0, 95.0, 97.0, 98.0, 95.0, 97.0, 97.0, 97.0, 97.0, 98.0, 95.0, 95.0, 108.0, 95.0, 95.0, 95.0, 91.0, 78.0, 83.0, 82.0, 92.0, 89.0, 88.0, 85.0, 86.0, 94.0, 94.0, 97.0, 99.0, 99.0, 97.0, 95.0, 91.0, 92.0, 94.0, 95.0, 92.0, 94.0, 94.0, 95.0, 92.0, 94.0, 94.0, 95.0, 95.0, 92.0, 94.0, 97.0, 95.0, 95.0, 94.0, 102.0, 104.0, 99.0, 98.0, 95.0, 94.0, 91.0, 94.0, 94.0, 91.0, 92.0, 91.0, 92.0, 97.0, 94.0, 92.0, 91.0, 97.0, 95.0, 109.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 110.0, 112.0, 112.0, 109.0, 110.0, 112.0, 109.0, 105.0, 104.0, 102.0, 100.0, 105.0, 102.0, 102.0, 105.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 104.0, 104.0, 105.0, 107.0, 102.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 105.0, 105.0, 104.0, 104.0, 107.0, 104.0, 102.0, 105.0, 105.0, 105.0, 105.0, 105.0, 105.0, 107.0, 105.0, 102.0, 104.0, 104.0, 104.0, 105.0, 107.0, 105.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 105.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 110.0, 112.0, 107.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 105.0, 109.0, 110.0, 109.0, 110.0, 107.0, 112.0, 117.0, 110.0, 109.0, 116.0, 114.0, 112.0, 112.0, 110.0, 110.0, 109.0, 104.0, 112.0, 116.0, 114.0, 116.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 110.0, 109.0, 105.0, 112.0, 114.0, 110.0, 110.0, 114.0, 116.0, 112.0, 107.0, 112.0, 107.0, 110.0, 109.0, 110.0, 107.0, 109.0, 110.0, 114.0, 110.0, 110.0, 114.0, 112.0, 112.0, 116.0, 117.0, 117.0, 117.0, 114.0, 114.0, 109.0, 109.0, 110.0, 107.0, 109.0, 110.0, 109.0, 109.0, 107.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 114.0, 110.0, 107.0, 109.0, 110.0, 109.0, 110.0, 114.0, 112.0, 109.0, 114.0, 110.0, 112.0, 114.0, 116.0, 110.0, 112.0, 112.0, 119.0, 121.0, 119.0, 117.0, 114.0, 110.0, 114.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 105.0, 104.0, 105.0, 105.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 104.0, 105.0, 102.0, 105.0, 102.0, 107.0, 104.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 109.0, 112.0, 110.0, 110.0, 110.0, 112.0, 109.0, 110.0, 107.0, 107.0, 112.0, 110.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 114.0, 112.0, 109.0, 107.0, 112.0, 109.0, 110.0, 107.0, 110.0, 112.0, 112.0, 109.0, 105.0, 105.0, 105.0, 109.0, 107.0, 110.0, 109.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 112.0, 114.0, 109.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 105.0, 107.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 104.0, 107.0, 116.0, 114.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 110.0, 110.0, 107.0, 95.0, 94.0, 80.0, 83.0, 85.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0, 98.0, 98.0, 97.0, 100.0, 104.0, 107.0, 105.0, 102.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 102.0, 102.0, 100.0, 104.0, 107.0, 105.0, 107.0, 104.0, 102.0, 104.0, 102.0, 102.0, 102.0, 104.0, 117.0, 98.0, 102.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 100.0, 100.0, 104.0, 107.0, 107.0, 104.0, 104.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 104.0, 104.0, 104.0, 107.0, 110.0, 112.0, 112.0, 109.0, 105.0, 119.0, 104.0, 91.0, 88.0, 95.0, 105.0, 104.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 109.0, 105.0, 100.0, 102.0, 104.0, 104.0, 105.0, 104.0, 105.0, 102.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 102.0, 100.0, 104.0, 104.0, 109.0, 105.0, 104.0, 114.0, 116.0, 112.0, 110.0, 110.0, 112.0, 107.0, 112.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 105.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 102.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 107.0, 102.0, 105.0, 107.0, 109.0, 112.0, 109.0, 107.0, 104.0, 105.0, 105.0, 107.0, 105.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 110.0, 110.0, 109.0, 105.0, 105.0, 104.0, 107.0, 104.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 104.0, 104.0, 107.0, 105.0, 102.0, 102.0, 104.0, 105.0, 102.0, 107.0, 105.0, 107.0, 104.0, 107.0, 105.0, 102.0, 104.0, 102.0, 105.0, 105.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 107.0, 109.0, 107.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 110.0, 109.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 107.0, 110.0, 107.0, 109.0, 105.0, 109.0, 107.0, 109.0, 109.0, 110.0, 109.0, 104.0, 104.0, 110.0, 112.0, 112.0, 114.0, 117.0, 112.0, 114.0, 112.0, 112.0, 110.0, 121.0, 117.0, 117.0, 112.0, 114.0, 116.0, 110.0, 109.0, 112.0, 110.0, 110.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 105.0, 105.0, 100.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 105.0, 109.0, 105.0, 107.0, 102.0, 102.0, 107.0, 104.0, 105.0, 104.0, 100.0, 102.0, 102.0, 102.0, 107.0, 107.0, 105.0, 102.0, 98.0, 102.0, 105.0, 105.0, 107.0, 109.0, 107.0, 100.0, 100.0, 98.0, 100.0, 100.0, 102.0, 102.0, 102.0, 102.0, 104.0, 107.0, 104.0, 107.0, 105.0, 102.0, 105.0, 107.0, 112.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 105.0, 105.0, 105.0, 109.0, 109.0, 107.0, 109.0, 110.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 102.0, 102.0, 107.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 109.0, 105.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 116.0, 110.0, 107.0, 107.0, 116.0, 110.0, 104.0, 107.0, 107.0, 110.0, 116.0, 116.0, 119.0, 112.0, 112.0, 109.0, 109.0, 107.0, 110.0, 114.0, 112.0, 110.0, 116.0, 109.0, 110.0, 110.0, 116.0, 110.0, 109.0, 110.0, 107.0, 107.0, 105.0, 107.0, 114.0, 109.0, 109.0, 105.0, 105.0, 102.0, 109.0, 109.0, 105.0, 107.0, 105.0, 104.0, 105.0, 109.0, 107.0, 105.0, 112.0, 114.0, 112.0, 114.0, 116.0, 118.0, 115.0, 115.0, 115.0, 116.0, 122.0, 118.0, 116.0, 115.0, 113.0, 113.0, 113.0, 116.0, 118.0, 118.0, 120.0, 118.0, 115.0, 109.0, 111.0, 116.0, 113.0, 111.0, 113.0, 120.0, 118.0, 115.0, 115.0, 113.0, 115.0, 111.0, 111.0, 107.0, 107.0, 106.0, 107.0, 106.0, 107.0, 111.0, 116.0, 115.0, 109.0, 111.0, 111.0, 109.0, 109.0, 113.0, 111.0, 113.0, 111.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 107.0, 109.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 107.0, 106.0, 106.0, 106.0, 107.0, 106.0, 104.0, 104.0, 111.0, 107.0, 104.0, 104.0, 104.0, 106.0, 106.0, 104.0, 107.0, 107.0, 104.0, 109.0, 124.0, 120.0, 115.0, 115.0, 113.0, 111.0, 113.0, 113.0, 118.0, 115.0, 116.0, 115.0, 115.0, 115.0, 115.0, 113.0, 115.0, 113.0, 99.0, 96.0, 104.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 111.0, 111.0, 111.0, 113.0, 113.0, 118.0, 116.0, 115.0, 111.0, 109.0, 109.0, 107.0, 109.0, 115.0, 111.0, 111.0, 113.0, 115.0, 111.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 111.0, 115.0, 115.0, 111.0, 109.0, 113.0, 116.0, 115.0, 115.0, 120.0, 116.0, 120.0, 115.0, 111.0, 113.0, 111.0, 113.0, 109.0, 107.0, 111.0, 106.0, 107.0, 113.0, 111.0, 115.0, 111.0, 107.0, 107.0, 111.0, 113.0, 109.0, 106.0, 107.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 107.0, 106.0, 107.0, 109.0, 111.0, 107.0, 107.0, 111.0, 113.0, 107.0, 109.0, 115.0, 109.0, 111.0, 107.0, 107.0, 111.0, 109.0, 111.0, 111.0, 111.0, 109.0, 111.0, 113.0, 115.0, 111.0, 116.0, 111.0, 106.0, 111.0, 107.0, 109.0, 106.0, 106.0, 107.0, 104.0, 104.0, 109.0, 109.0, 107.0, 106.0, 106.0, 107.0, 111.0, 109.0, 113.0, 111.0, 107.0, 111.0, 111.0, 109.0, 109.0, 111.0, 115.0, 113.0, 111.0, 115.0, 115.0, 113.0, 111.0, 116.0, 115.0, 115.0, 113.0, 113.0, 113.0, 113.0, 113.0, 115.0, 116.0, 116.0, 116.0, 113.0, 113.0, 109.0, 109.0, 115.0, 109.0, 100.0, 96.0, 89.0, 107.0, 104.0, 104.0, 109.0, 106.0, 111.0, 109.0, 104.0, 107.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 104.0, 107.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 115.0, 113.0, 109.0, 113.0, 109.0, 107.0, 106.0, 106.0, 109.0, 106.0, 104.0, 106.0, 106.0, 107.0, 107.0, 106.0, 109.0, 111.0, 109.0, 111.0, 111.0, 107.0, 111.0, 109.0, 111.0, 109.0, 106.0, 102.0, 106.0, 104.0, 102.0, 102.0, 102.0, 104.0, 109.0, 109.0, 106.0, 107.0, 109.0, 113.0, 115.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 102.0, 104.0, 106.0, 106.0, 107.0, 106.0, 111.0, 111.0, 107.0, 106.0, 104.0, 107.0, 106.0, 104.0, 109.0, 111.0, 111.0, 113.0, 107.0, 104.0, 106.0, 107.0, 109.0, 113.0, 109.0, 111.0, 116.0, 116.0, 115.0, 107.0, 107.0, 113.0, 109.0, 106.0, 102.0, 104.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 106.0, 104.0, 102.0, 107.0, 106.0, 104.0, 102.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 104.0, 111.0, 113.0, 113.0, 107.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 104.0, 106.0, 106.0, 109.0, 115.0, 113.0, 113.0, 111.0, 111.0, 111.0, 106.0, 109.0, 106.0, 106.0, 102.0, 102.0, 102.0, 102.0, 100.0, 102.0, 100.0, 100.0, 99.0, 97.0, 99.0, 100.0, 100.0, 99.0, 100.0, 99.0, 102.0, 104.0, 102.0, 99.0, 99.0, 102.0, 102.0, 100.0, 97.0, 97.0, 97.0, 97.0, 100.0, 99.0, 111.0, 111.0, 109.0, 107.0, 104.0, 115.0, 111.0, 111.0, 113.0, 115.0, 113.0, 115.0, 109.0, 109.0, 111.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 104.0, 106.0, 116.0, 115.0, 111.0, 111.0, 106.0, 106.0, 111.0, 107.0, 111.0, 111.0, 109.0, 106.0, 106.0, 104.0, 102.0, 104.0, 104.0, 106.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 100.0, 104.0, 102.0, 100.0, 99.0, 99.0, 100.0, 99.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 99.0, 100.0, 97.0, 99.0, 97.0, 102.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 99.0, 99.0, 97.0, 99.0, 97.0, 99.0, 96.0, 97.0, 96.0, 97.0, 96.0, 100.0, 104.0, 100.0, 104.0, 102.0, 106.0, 106.0, 104.0, 104.0, 102.0, 99.0, 113.0, 115.0, 109.0, 107.0, 111.0, 111.0, 113.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 115.0, 124.0, 124.0, 115.0, 118.0, 116.0, 115.0, 113.0, 122.0, 120.0, 116.0, 122.0, 118.0, 118.0, 120.0, 109.0, 113.0, 115.0, 111.0, 113.0, 113.0, 115.0, 116.0, 113.0, 115.0, 118.0, 115.0, 113.0, 113.0, 109.0, 107.0, 113.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 106.0, 107.0, 113.0, 118.0, 122.0, 122.0, 118.0, 118.0, 122.0, 120.0, 118.0, 113.0, 115.0, 115.0, 111.0, 120.0, 60.0, 116.0, 115.0, 115.0, 115.0, 113.0, 113.0, 113.0, 115.0, 111.0, 113.0, 109.0, 113.0, 111.0, 109.0, 99.0, 100.0, 96.0, 99.0, 102.0, 109.0, 102.0, 104.0, 111.0, 107.0, 107.0, 104.0, 107.0, 109.0, 107.0, 102.0, 104.0, 107.0, 109.0, 107.0, 106.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 106.0, 111.0, 106.0, 104.0, 107.0, 111.0, 111.0, 107.0, 113.0, 109.0, 111.0, 109.0, 104.0, 106.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 111.0, 113.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 111.0, 113.0, 111.0, 107.0, 109.0, 109.0, 106.0, 113.0, 109.0, 111.0, 109.0, 106.0, 109.0, 111.0, 107.0, 106.0, 107.0, 111.0, 113.0, 111.0, 109.0, 107.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 115.0, 115.0, 109.0, 116.0, 113.0, 109.0, 111.0, 116.0, 120.0, 113.0, 111.0, 113.0, 113.0, 111.0, 113.0, 111.0, 109.0, 107.0, 115.0, 115.0, 111.0, 113.0, 107.0, 107.0, 109.0, 109.0, 111.0, 111.0, 111.0, 111.0, 111.0, 113.0, 111.0, 113.0, 115.0, 111.0, 115.0, 111.0, 111.0, 111.0, 111.0, 109.0, 113.0, 115.0, 111.0, 109.0, 106.0, 109.0, 106.0, 109.0, 106.0, 111.0, 111.0, 113.0, 111.0, 111.0, 113.0, 111.0, 111.0, 109.0, 111.0, 109.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 111.0, 109.0, 113.0, 115.0, 111.0, 109.0, 109.0, 109.0, 116.0, 116.0, 115.0, 115.0, 113.0, 109.0, 106.0, 107.0, 107.0, 107.0, 106.0, 104.0, 104.0, 107.0, 107.0, 106.0, 104.0, 102.0, 102.0, 104.0, 102.0, 102.0, 106.0, 106.0, 104.0, 102.0, 100.0, 111.0, 109.0, 115.0, 128.0, 128.0, 120.0, 120.0, 120.0, 115.0, 116.0, 115.0, 115.0, 118.0, 120.0, 120.0, 124.0, 115.0, 118.0, 113.0, 111.0, 115.0, 113.0, 113.0, 113.0, 109.0, 107.0, 113.0, 111.0, 113.0, 109.0, 111.0, 107.0, 106.0, 107.0, 111.0, 111.0, 109.0, 111.0, 111.0, 109.0, 106.0, 106.0, 104.0, 104.0, 106.0, 107.0, 111.0, 109.0, 106.0, 106.0, 109.0, 107.0, 106.0, 111.0, 115.0, 111.0, 109.0, 113.0, 115.0, 115.0, 109.0, 109.0, 111.0, 111.0, 109.0, 120.0, 115.0, 113.0, 115.0, 116.0, 111.0, 109.0, 113.0, 116.0, 118.0, 106.0, 99.0, 89.0, 97.0, 99.0, 100.0, 107.0, 104.0]

let labels = data.map((el, i) => (Math.round(30 / data.length * i).toString()))

const options = {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels,
    datasets: [{
      data,
      label: "Output",
      fill: false,
      pointRadius: 0,
      borderColor: 'orange',
      backgroundColor: 'orange'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      intersect: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          callback: (label, index) => (label % 5 === 0 ? label : '')
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }]
    }

  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Might want to filter out the duplicates for the labels array and replace them with something not devidebly by 5 to make it a bit better